# Block Probe Requests (SSID leak / active WiFi scan)

Tags: wi-fi

I have a simple question. I don't want my Android devices to do active WiFi scans because this way the SSIDs of all APs the device has ever connected to get leaked.

How can I block all probe requests? Could it be done using iptables?

(I don't care about the fact that auto connecting takes a few seconds longer if you only do passive scans. I don't care about closed-source apps like Pry Fi. I don't want to disable WiFi when I'm not using it. I don't want to use apps like Wi-Fi Privacy Police that alter the WiFi scans depending on your GPS location.)